# On complete behaving weird in primefaces calendar

Tags: jsf, primefaces

This is my primefaces code

```
   <p:calendar id="cal1" showButtonPanel="true">
    <p:ajax event="close" oncomplete="clear1();"/>
</p:calendar>
 <p:calendar id="cal2"  showButtonPanel="true">
    <p:ajax event="close" oncomplete="clear2()"/>
</p:calendar>
```

The issue is when invoke second calendar also the first javascript method I defined gets called. I checked my code twice and I was correctly calling the method? Can somebody please tell me why this is behaving like this? I am really confused

edit 1:
 Also this is what I am trying in that:

```
     function clear1(){
         $(document).on('click', '.ui-datepicker-close', function () {
          clearValue();
        });
    }
    function clearValue(){
    document.getElementById("form:cal1_input").value="";
    }

  function clear2(){
         $(document).on('click', '.ui-datepicker-close', function () {
          clearValue1();
        });
    }
    function clearValue1(){
    document.getElementById("form:cal2_input").value="";
    }
```

And whenever I close calendar it opens the first method twice and second method twice :( I checked it via alerts.And this method works correctly when there is a single calendar and fails in case of multiple calendars

Comment: For me with PF 6.2 the correct method is invoked each time a calendar is closed.

Comment: Hi, I am also using 6.2 only, And whenever I close calander it opens the first method twice and second method twice :(  I checked it via alerts.Updated the method details in edit

Comment: You should consider editing your question to provide a [mcve]

Comment: can anyone say where i am getting wrong? pls I am supposed to clear the specific date selected but this is clearing all dates selected. pls pls someone help?

Comment: edited @Selaron can you pls have a look now?

Comment: And also this works correctly with only a single calander.problem arises with multiple calander only.

Comment: It's still very incomplete. Please provide an [mcve]

Comment: Hi @Selaron updated with the code that I am trying.

Comment: `document.getElementById("form:cal2_input").val("");` fails with `TypeError: document.getElementById(...).val is not a function`

Comment: It was a typo :( I was trying jquery for this.Now updated it was value. can you please try now?

Comment: On each closure of a calendar you **add** an actionlistener to **every** calendars' close button (with css class .ui-datepicker-close) present in your document that invokes some `clearValue*()` method. This way you end up with both method invocations in the `.ui-datepicker-close` buttons' event queue.

Comment: Ok I now understand.Thanks a lot for your reply. Is there any better way to handle this? I am still a learner and trying to do something, but failing miserably. Please help me with any references.basically I am trying to clear the value when ever user clicks close button on the button panel of primefaces calander.

Comment: Please prevent the XY-Problem in future questions ;-)   https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to turn the "done" button into a "clear" button. A solved issue exists for this but I cannot find a clear button on calendar component: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/506

Possibly you should use the datePicker which has a clear button: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/datePicker.xhtml

Comment: Thanks alot. but I am using 6.2 version which did not has the clear button :( so trying all these things.thanks for your help :).Just exploring some other way to get this to done on 6.2  version

Comment: @user3729090 you can test the datePicker using the first release candidate of PrimeFaces 7: https://www.primefaces.org/primefaces-7-0-rc1-released/